# How to send a put-request with body in Angular with ngResource

Tags: angularjs, put, ngresource

I can send a put-request with a header with ngResource. My FactoryService looks like this:

```
angular
.module("playersServicesModule", ["ngResource", "config"])
.factory("playersService", ["$resource", "API_ROOT",

  function ($resource, API_ROOT) {
    "use strict";

    var url = API_ROOT + "/api/footballplayers";

    return {

      updateFootballPlayer: function (id, column, newValue) {

        return $resource(url + '/:Id', { Id: id },
                {
                  "update": {
                    method: 'PUT', headers: {
                      "Column": column,
                      "NewValue": newValue
                    }
                  }
                });
      }

    };
```

How can i add data to the body of the put-request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

A suggested update to your factory would be the following:

```
angular
.module("playersServicesModule", ["ngResource", "config"])
.factory("playersService", ["$resource", "API_ROOT",

    function ($resource, API_ROOT) {
        "use strict";

        var url = API_ROOT + "/api/footballplayers";

        var myResource = $resource(url + '/:Id',
                { Id: '@id },
                {
                    "update": {
                        method: 'PUT'
                    }
                });

        return {

            updateFootballPlayer: function (id, column, newValue) {

                return myResource.update(
                    {Id: id},
                    {
                        column: column,
                        newValue: newValue
                    },
                    function (successResponse) {
                        // Do something on success
                    },
                    function (failResponse) {
                        // Do something on fail
                    }
                );
            }

        };
    });
```

**ORIGINAL**

You add data to the body when you perform the actual request e.g.

```
$resource(url + '/:Id', { Id: id },
    {
        "update": {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                "Column": column,
                "NewValue": newValue
            }
         }
    }
).update(
    {},
    <BODY_OBJECT>,
    function (successResponse) {},
    function (failResponse) {}
);
```

Your object to pass as body data will replace the `<BODY_OBJECT>`.

Comment: The $resource doesn't perform the $http PUT request, it just creates the object you can create requests using. You have to call the `update` action that you defined on it to perform the actual PUT request.

Comment: Updated with a suggested edit to your factory (removed headers and placed as the body object for the request).